# Noun phrase after "show"

Tags: verbs, gerunds, present-participles, noun-phrases

The following sentences all involve the verb "show" followed by a noun phrase. Number 6 sounds a bit weird, and the last one is just wrong — but why is that?

> 1. The video shows the differences between them.
> 2. The video shows them being different/the same.
> 3. The purpose of the video is to show the differences between them.
> 4. The purpose of the video is to show them being different/the same.
> 5. The video shows the effects of smoking.
> 6. The video shows smoking being unhealthy.
> 7. The purpose of the video is to show the effects of smoking.
> 8. The purpose of the video is to show smoking being unhealthy.

These are "grammatically correct", meaning they meet the expectation (as of now) of how verbs/nouns/etc go together. I'm interested in the reason why the two sound *awkward*. In particular, I want to know what it is that people expect to hear after "show" which distinguishes 6,8 from 2,4, for instance.

Comment: What is wrong with 6 and 8? They may sound a little awkward, but they're not ungrammatical.

Comment: To make them a little less awkward you might say, "... show[s] smoking *as* being unhealthy."

Comment: @Robusto Being awkward is what I meant. Of course one can make up tons of phrases which are extremely awkward to vocalise without being "grammatically incorrect". Although I'm not a native speaker, I could certainly have looked up grammatical rules in a dictionary by myself, unless you're saying stackexchange is no more than a dictionary? I tagged the question as a usage question precisely because I don't think it has anything to with grammar.

Comment: Normally when I encounter what I feel is awkward, like #6, I see that as a hint to use another word. In that case, perhaps "demonstrate" would be more suitable.

Comment: @hwhm: All right, given what you said I have provided an answer.

Comment: What @hwhm said. #6 is "unhappy" because it would normally be phrased as *"The video shows smoking **is** unhealthy"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've commented as much, but I think there should be an answer so people can vote on it.

OP's #6 and #8 aren't "valid", in my opinion, because they're not intended to mean the video shows an isolated instance of smoking *being* unhealthy. They're showing smoking ***is*** unhealthy. Always.

If it had been *This video shows John being stupid*, that wouldn't imply John is *always* stupid. Personally, I'd say it almost implies the opposite, since if you were trying to make a case for John being inherently stupid you'd almost certainly say *This video shows/demonstrates John is stupid*.

---

By similar reasoning, OP's #2 and #4 are also at the very least poor phrasing. Reasonable alternatives include...

> 2a. *The video shows **they are** different/the same.*
>    2b. *The video shows them **to be** different/the same.*
>    4a. *The purpose of the video is to show them **as** [being] different/the same.*

The reason present continuous *[being]* is an "acceptable" option (but not *preferred*, in my opinion), in #4a is because the word *"as"* implies they're being shown *as they really are* (a continuous state, not just the way they happen to be at the time of appearing in some particular video).

Comment: So do you mean, by the same logic, that sentence #2 ("The video shows them being different") also contains the implication that the things being compared are *not* expected to be different?

Comment: @hwhm: I hadn't really considered #2 and #4 - but yes, I consider those to be "unhappy" sentences as well. I'll edit to reflect that.

Comment: @hwhm: Also just realised you asked something about *expectations*. I don't think any of these variations are affected by whether the audience (or the speaker, before having seen the video) might or might not expect or believe what it's going to show them.

Answer (score 2):

The awkwardness stems from close proximity of two words ending in *-ing* that need to be parsed differently. In your example, *smoking* is a noun made from a verb, but the reader may attempt to parse it as a part of a noun phrase and then come up short when the very next word needs to be parsed similarly, but with a different outcome.

We experience no such difficulty with a parallel construction:

> The picture shows John being funny.

We know how to parse John, and "being funny" retreats from the awkward into the unremarkable.

Comment: Another case of [Doubl-_ing_](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/93707/15299).

Comment: I don't agree that *show John being funny* is exactly parallel to *show smoking being unhealthy*. In John's case, the showing is specifically concerned with presenting *a particular incident* where John is funny - usually with no implication that John is *always* funny, and that the audience might need to be informed of this fact. In support of this I suggest you can easily replace John's one with *illustrate*, but that doesn't normally work with smoking (unless, say, the video shows someone setting fire to their hair while trying to light a cigarette! :)

Comment: @Robusto. I see the collocation of *smoking being* as awkward. But removing the immediate juxtaposition, as in "This is a picture *showing* John *being* funny" seems more natural. Am I following your point? Does this help?

Comment: @JohnLawler If I'm not mistaken, Doubl-ing refers to the juxtaposition of two present participles. "Smoking" isn't used as a present participle here.

Comment: @Jim I don't think that's what Robusto meant. "Smoking" is parsed as a noun, while "being" is parsed as part of a gerund clause, hence the awkwardness. In your example, both "showing" and "being" are parsed *with the same outcome*, each as part of a gerund clause.

Comment: @Jim: I think that would work better, to be sure. But that is not the question.

Comment: @Fumble: You're missing the point of what I'm saying. And you're missing saying something cogent about the matter at hand. What does *illustrate* have to do with anything here?

Comment: @Robusto: I think you're missing the point. It's not a matter of verb/noun conflation. Replace *smoking/unhealthy* with *cancer/unpleasant*, for example, and you'll see the same problem is still there in 6 & 8.

Comment: ...the "illustrate" bit was because that's the intended sense of "show" in OP's sentences. Not "replays a captured recording of an instance of something happening".

Comment: I agree. I'm missing your point because it has nothing to do with my point.

Comment: I'm lost. Your post *seems* to say the problem (with #6 & #8?) revolves around the double-ing. But if we replace *smoking* by *intoxication*, say, the same problem is still there - *being* is the wrong verb form when you're *showing X to be Y* (i.e. - *showing that X **is** Y*).