# Is it correct to use two present participles sequentially?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, syntactic-analysis, present-participles

> We are currently in the process of **finishing planning** for the outage.

1. It the preceding sentence grammatically correct?
2. Is the preceding sentence ideally structured?
3. If not, what would be a better way of saying it?

Comment: That is a good question! :)

Comment: You might want to tweak the title, for those two verbs seem to have the shape of *present participle* verbs.

Comment: Remember that in this context *planning* acts as a noun.... *I finished planning for the wedding.*

Comment: As your ear probably told you, the two "-ing" words like that in a row seems to sound awkward. :)

Comment: As your ear will also tell you, two "-ing" words a row can be perfectly grammatical. Even three can be. Even four.

Comment: Neither is really a verb.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *"We are currently in the process of* ***finishing planning*** *for the outage."*

There can be grammatical constraints on some types of double "-ing" phrases.

I'll mention some of them here, and let you decide how applicable they are to your example.

**Double** ***-ing*** **constraint:**

*CGEL* page 1243-4:

> The double-*ing* constraint
>
> Some verbs that license gerund-participial complements cannot themselves occur in the gerund-participle form when they have such a complement. Compare:
>
> [37]
>
> - i a. *They started quarreling.* - - - b. (*) *They are starting quarreling.*
> - ii a. *The lawn needs mowing.* - - - b. (*) *The lawn is always needing mowing.*
> - iii a. *We considered buying one.* - - - b. *We are considering buying one.*
>
> The succession of gerund-participles in [i.b/ii.b] is excluded by what is known as the 'double-*ing* constraint'. As evident from [iii.b], it applies to only a subset of catenative verbs -- a small subset, in fact. The clearest cases are aspectual verbs such as *begin, cease, continue, start, stop,* and verbs taking concealed passives, like *need* i [ii]. We should probably also include others, such as *intend*, but there is a good deal of variation between speakers as to their acceptance of the [b] construction. We noted in &1.1. that gerund-participials cannot have the progressive auxiliary *be* as head ( (*)*They accused him of being running away when the alarm sounded*), and this can be seen as a special case of the constraint.

Note that *"finish"* is an aspectual verb. *CGEL* page 1228:

> Most aspectual verbs have raised subjects, . . . there are, however, a few that have ordinary subjects, normally with an agentive interpretation: *discontinue, finish, quit, resume . . .*

*CGEL* page 1174 fn1:

> Examples with progressive *be* are occasionally encountered in casual speech: *I've missed endless busses through [not being standing at the bus stop when they arrived].* This cannot, however, be regarded as an established construction in Present-day English.

It seems that you have got yourself a good ear. :)

Note that *CGEL* is the 2002 reference grammar by Huddleston and Pullum et al., *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (CGEL).

Comment: Does the (*) mean 'arguably ungrammatical'? My perception is that 'The lawn is always needing mowing.' sounds a lot more acceptable than 'They are starting quarreling.'

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of what Ross (1970) calls the "[Doubl-*ing* Constraint](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/93707/15299)".

[Zwicky (1999) is a very clear introduction](http://www.stanford.edu/%7Ezwicky/gerund-participles.pdf) to the phenomenon, with excellent examples, including

- *It continues to rain.*
- *It continues raining.*
- *It is continuing to rain.*

which are all grammatical, compared to the ungrammatical

- **It is continuing raining.*

Comment: So OP's sentence is ungrammatical, right? I am confused because another answer says that sentence is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine. They're not both acting as verbs, which you can see with a slight mod: "...finishing our planning for..."

Comment: Here, I think that _planning_ is functioning partly as a verb and partly as a noun. It has attributes of both. Perhaps for that reason, I personally find the similarity of the form of 'finishing' and 'planning' coupled with the difference in their function a little jarring, though I would not call this type of construction _wrong_ or _unacceptable_.

Comment: Small beer! I can't see anything particularly unusual about [*Instructions are **not** included for making working landing gear.*](http://www.paragrafix.biz/product_detail.asp?PPartNum=pgx177)

Comment: @ErikKowai That 'jarring' effect is known as *horror aequi*.

Comment: @StoneyB - Thanks for that extra info. (Now to manufacture some pretext in which I can casually drop it into my next interaction with a supermarket cashier...  :-)

Comment: @StoneyB: I upvoted this answer mainly for the first two words, but it seems to me both *finishing* and *planning* are essential "verb" usages here. And although I don't have a *big* problem with OP's example, in actual fact I find my own example with three consecutive *-ing* forms less "jarring". I think it's significant that your earlier-cited [*horror aequi*](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/15380/126) definition specifically says *identical or similar **grammatical** structures*. The more distinct grammatical/syntactic roles in my example are enough to allay any disquiet for me, at least.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, both of these are gerunds.