# Helping [to] + infinitive verb?

Tags: verbs, syntactic-analysis, infinitives, present-continuous

What would be correct? And why?

- I'm helping maintain the library.
- I'm helping to maintain the library.
- I'm helping maintaining the library.
- I'm helping in maintaining the library. (ok this one sounds quite wrong)

Comment: The last one is fine: it indicates maintaining the library is a huge project, in which you're helping, perhaps temporarily. It's the third one which is awkward.

Comment: (3) is out by the [Doubl-_ing_ constraint](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/167751/15299), and (4) is OK. (1) and (2) are both OK, because [_help_ can take an infinitive with or without _to_](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/50035/15299).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the verb 'help' with or without a 'to infinitive'. The meaning remains the same.

You don't help yourself but you help others.
Your third sentence sounds like you're helping yourself in maintaining the library.

I'm helping _ in maintaining the library. You don't fill in that blank. The object of help could be anything but you.

Comment: Also worth noting: While "I'm helping in maintaining the library" is not right, "I help in maintaining the library" is correct.

Comment: So which answer would make the most sense if the question is "What have you been doing lately?"

Comment: @CristianoCoelho: *I've been helping maintain the library.*