# "Keeping moving forward is important" - felicitous or not?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

**Is the following sentence felicitous or not? If it is, why?**

> *Keeping moving* forward is important.

The "keeping moving" is what bothers me, it sounds pretty weird to me. I am a nonnative speaker, though, so I'd like to hear some feedback from native speakers.

Comment: This is known in syntactic circles as the "Doubl-_ing_ Constraint". Some discussion [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/167751/15299) and [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/93707/15299).

Comment: Enjoying dancing is the only requirement.  
Going fishing is the perfect way to spend a Saturday morning.  
Regretting saying something insulting can keep you up at night.

Answer (score 1):

> Keeping moving forward is important.

Grammatically speaking it is perfectly correct. Stylistically I agree - it sounds a little clumsy.

Formally (as in a military handbook): *To keep moving forward is important.*

Conversationally: *It's important we/you keep moving forward.*

In general: *It's important to keep moving forward.*

There may be other contexts.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on why the sentence sounds clumsy?

Comment: Yes, it's simply because you have two consecutive words ending in '-ing'. As I say, there's no grammatical problem.