# Grammar - using the word 'considering' followed by action

Tags: grammaticality

So I was thinking of writing the following sentence:

> I am considering of changing isp companies

However the word **of** doesn't feel right. I thought about swapping it out with **to** but that sounds wrong as well. Can anyone confirm whether this is right or wrong or perhaps correct it?

Otherwise I might have to just use consider:

> I will consider changing isp companies

Though this feels like it's different.

Comment: You don't need either. "Considering changing" is fine, just as you have used "consider changing" in your other example.

Comment: In a simple catenative construction, like that in your example, "consider" only licenses gerund-participial complements, so "I will consider changing isp companies" is the only choice.

Comment: @BillJ So the context of my sentence is that if my isp doesn't fix my internet I will search for other options. I.E. `If the internet does not stabalize then I am considering changing isp companies`. Would that be correct?

Comment: Yes. The problem is that having two present participles in a row sounds odd to many speakers. So verbs in the progressive that can take gerund complements generally don't; this is called [the Doubl _-ing_ Constraint.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/93707/15299)

Comment: The question is dealt with in some detail at: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167739/is-it-correct-to-use-two-present-verbs-sequentially

Comment: @RonaldSole The so-called doubl-_ing_ constraint does not apply to "consider", so there's nothing wrong with saying "I am considering changing companies".

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like: "... considering doing ..."

For example, "I am considering changing ISP companies."